# Why is the automapper in C# failing to map my Datetime values correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a repository pulling a list from a database in .Net Core. It returns data from a model called notes which contains UTC time of when the note was last updated. When I pass the list of Notes to my service and attempt to use Automapper to map the list to 'NotesForViewDto', everything is mapping correctly except my Datetime value. The Datetime value is returning '01/01/0001 00:00:00' after being mapped.

Note Repo:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Note>> GetNotesForProject(Guid instanceId)
    {
        //List of notes with same project and instanceid as project currently on
        var totalList = await _context.Note.Include(x=>x.Tags).Where(x=>x.InstanceId == instanceId).ToListAsync();

     //Debugging purposes - returns correct datetime from below loop before mapping

        foreach (var entry in totalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.LastUpdated);
        }

        return totalList;
    }
```

Note Service:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<NoteForViewDto>> GetNotesForProject(Guid projectId)
    {
        var notes = await _noteRepo.GetNotesForProject(_session.InstanceId, projectId);
        var list = _mapper.Map<NoteForViewDto[]>(notes);

     //Debugging purposes - returns incorrect datetime from below loop after mapping

        foreach (var entry in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.date);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Automapper Profile:

```
        CreateMap<Note, NoteForViewDto>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.name, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.DisplayName); })
             .ForMember(dest => dest.img, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.ProfileInfo.Image); })
             .ForMember(dest => dest.date, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.DateUpdated); });
```

NoteForViewDto:

```
public class NoteForViewDto
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public Guid projectId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public List<NoteTagsViewDto> tags { get; set; }

}
```

Note Model:

```
public class Note: DomainBase
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public Guid InstanceId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NoteTags> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Why is this so? The rest of the mapping is completed successfully, and as can be seen from the output window below the datetimes are correct before the mapping and yet display incorrect data after the mapping.

[image: Debug Output]

Comment: That value indicates a failure at parsing the values. What does the mapper actually do? What culture is it running under?

Comment: The mapper should be directly mapping the required values from the Note model to the NoteForViewDto

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Is it possible that the call you used to debug returns different data? I notice your first example and your second use a different way to get the data. Perhaps GetNotesForProject isn't returning the data properly?

Comment: According to your description , I create a demo to test your mapping profile and it show the datetime correctly.  The repository method used in your service is not the method you provide above. And the correct datetime before the mapping is the value of `LastUpdated` property, but  your mapping profile  maps the `DateUpdated` to the `date` of NoteForViewDto . Check if the `DateUpdated` property of  `Note` model has the correct value.